# Как заставить Laravel игнорировать ошибку?

Tags: php, laravel

Как сделать чтобы не выводилась страничка с ошибками в Laravel?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25599048/9435985

Answer (score 2):

В корневой директории у вас лежит файл .env
Вам нужно поменять строчку

`APP_ENV=production #указывает окружение в котором мы работаем`

`APP_DEBUG=false #запрещает логирование на уровне debug, оставляя только уровень error`

В папке `config` не стоит это менять. К примеру если вы работаете в команде, и используете гит, то эти изменения пойдут ко в всем, это не очень хорошо в случае, если вам нужен дебаг. а файл `.env` обычно в `gitignore` поскольку там хранится пароли от базы, и другие важные данные.